# Argument conversion with Iterables, Maps, Objects and?

Tags: java, generics, iterator, type-conversion

I have a variable of type:

```
Iterable<Map<String,Object>>
```

and I am trying to return it as type:

```
Iterable<Map<String,?>>
```

The compiler says:

```
argument mismatch; Iterable<Map<String,Object>>
cannot be converted to Iterable<Map<String,?>>
```

Does anybody know how to coerce the compiler into "doing the right thing" here, or is this somehow impossible?

Comment: Can you change the return type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Iterable<T>` should is a "Producer" of `Iterator<T>`, which is in turn a "Producer" of its type parameter `T` (there is only a method that returns `T`, and no method that takes `T`). Therefore, according to the PECS (Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`) rule, it should always be used with `extends` wildcards everywhere.

If you have a variable of type

```
Iterable<? extends Map<String,Object>>
```

and you return it as

```
Iterable<? extends Map<String,?>>
```

there is no problem. Whenever you get `Iterator` out of it, you will similarly type it as `Iterator<? extends Something>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always cast to an untyped Iterable and let the return statement perform an unchecked cast back to the type you want:

```
public static Iterable<Map<String, ?>> getIt() {
    Iterable<Map<String, Object>> t = null;
    return ((Iterable) t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the bludgeon method of just casting to the raw type (which can cause grief - see [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/823393)) you could always use a thin adapter requiring no casting at all thus maintaining all possible type safety:

```
// Could probably be done inline with a little tweaking.
class IMSQ implements Iterable<Map<String, ?>> {

    // The adaptee.
    final Iterable<Map<String, Object>> o;

    public IMSQ(Iterable<Map<String, Object>> o) {
        this.o = o;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Map<String, ?>> iterator() {
        // Pull a new Iterator out of it.
        final Iterator<Map<String, Object>> it = o.iterator();
        // Wrap it.
        return new Iterator<Map<String, ?>>() {

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return it.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, ?> next() {
                return it.next();
            }

        };
    }

}
```